# What are the actual quotas and rate limits for the DataManagement API

Tags: autodesk-forge, rate-limiting, quota

I know from [this page](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/developers_guide/rate-limiting/) that the DataManagement API has rate limiting, but I'm having a difficult time finding any information about what the rates actually are.

How many API calls can be made in what time period? 
Are there any quotas?

I was hoping to find a description like [this](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/developers_guide/quotas/) description for the rate limits and quotas for the Design Automation API, but I haven't had any success.

We know that we can handle the 429 error when we exceed rate limits. Handling the error is not our concern at the moment. We want to know the actual limits in order to judge the best method to do what we are trying to do, and also to judge how viable Forge is for our application in the long term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for letting us know and will let the portal team know to fill out the rate limit info.

In the meantime per our internal records S (50 RPM), M (300 RPM) and L-size (800 RPM) limits applies the following DM endpoints:

```
GET /projects/{project_id}/folders/{folder_id}  M   
GET /projects/{project_id}/folders/{folder_id}/parent   S   
GET /projects/{project_id}/folders/{folder_id}/contents M   
GET /projects/{project_id}/folders/{folder_id}/refs S   
GET /projects/{project_id}/folders/{folder_id}/relationships/refs   S   
GET /projects/{project_id}/folders/{folder_id}/relationships/links  S   
GET /projects/{project_id}/items/{item_id}  M   
GET /projects/{project_id}/items/{item_id}/parent   S   
GET /projects/{project_id}/items/{item_id}/refs M   
GET /projects/{project_id}/items/{item_id}/relationships/refs   S   
GET /projects/{project_id}/items/{item_id}/relationships/links  S   
GET /projects/{project_id}/items/{item_id}/tip  S   
GET /projects/{project_id}/items/{item_id}/versions L   
GET /projects/{project_id}/versions/{version_id}    M   
GET /projects/{project_id}/versions/{version_id}/item   S   
GET /projects/{project_id}/versions/{version_id}/refs"  S   
GET /projects/{project_id}/versions/{version_id}/relationships/refs S   
GET /projects/{project_id}/versions/{version_id}/relationships/links    S   
GET /projects/{project_id}/versions/{version_id}/downloads  S   
GET /projects/{project_id}/versions/{version_id}/downloadFormats    S   
GET /projects/{project_id}/jobs/{job_id}    M   
GET /projects/{project_id}/downloads/{download_id}  M   
GET /projects/{project_id}/folders/{folder_id}/search   M   
POST    /projects/{project_id}/storage  M   
POST    /projects/{project_id}/items    S   
POST    /projects/{project_id}/versions M   
POST    /projects/{project_id}/folders/{folder_id}/relationships/refs   S   
POST    /projects/{project_id}/items/{item_id}/relationships/refs   S   
POST    /projects/{project_id}/versions/{version_id}/relationships/refs S   
PATCH   /projects/{project_id}/items/{item_id}  S   
PATCH   /projects/{project_id}/versions/{version_id}    S   
POST    /projects/{project_id}/downloads    S   
POST    /projects/{project_id}/commands M   
POST    /projects/{project_id}/versions/{version_id}/relationships/links    S   
PATCH   /projects/{project_id}/versions/{version_id}/relationships/links/{link_id}  S   
POST    /projects/{project_id}/folders  S   
PATCH   /projects/{project_id}/folders/{folder_id}  S   
GET /hubs   S   
GET /hubs/{hub_id}  S   
GET /hubs/{hub_id}/projects S   
GET /hubs/{hub_id}/projects/{project_id}    S   
GET /hubs/{hub_id}/projects/{project_id}/hub    S   
GET /hubs/{hub_id}/projects/{project_id}/topFolders M
```

**NOTE: Above is not yet official and might change w/o prior notice so pls stay tuned to updates to the official dev portal**